# Difference between OCaml Type casting

Tags: types, casting, ocaml

What is the differences between Ocaml type casting / conversion methods below?

```
let a = (float) b ;;
```

And

```
let a = float_of_int b ;;
```

(Consider a is a float and b is an integer.)
Is there any advantage one over another? or are they same?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no general type casting mechanism in OCaml. There happens to be a function named `float` that does the same thing as `float_of_int`. You can use either one, with or without the extra parentheses.

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.03.0

# float 3;;
- : float = 3.
# float_of_int 3;;
- : float = 3.
# (float) 3;;
- : float = 3.
# (float_of_int) 3;;
- : float = 3.
```

But there's no function named (say) `int`:

```
# int 3.1;;
Error: Unbound value int
# (int) 3.0;;
Error: Unbound value int
```

Type casting as in C (and related languages) wouldn't really be compatible with the strong type system of OCaml.

Comment: Interesting how `(float)` doesn't result in the (erroneous) application of `float` to 0 arguments (erroneous because it expects an `int` argument). I should revisit the syntax..

Comment: OCaml functions are first class values, and you can always use them with fewer arguments than they take, including 0. Parenthesizing any expression is allowed, and a function name (being a first class value) is an expression.

Comment: @HunanRostomyan The function call syntax in OCaml is simply `expression expression` where the first expression needs to evaluate to a function. Note that no parentheses are part of that syntax. Parentheses are simply used to group expressions and can be added around any expression (like you could write `(1) + (2)` if you wanted to).

Answer (score 8):

According to their definitions in the [pervasives](https://github.com/lucasaiu/ocaml/blob/master/stdlib/pervasives.ml) module, `float` and `float_of_int` are two identical functions:

```
external float : int -> float = "%floatofint"
external float_of_int : int -> float = "%floatofint"
```

Furthermore, the style of writing  `(float) b` is not type casting. It is still a function application. The parentheses used here don't mean type casting, but they can be considered as parts of the expression.

For example, the following three expressions are the same:

```
let a = (float) b;;

let a = (float b);;

let a = float b;;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
let a = (float) b
```

is interpreted by the syntax rules as

```
let a = float b
```

where `float` is a function of type `int -> float` and happens to be the same function as `float_of_int`. This is not a type conversion as the C-like statement

```
double a = (float)b;
```

which has no equivalent in OCaml.